# Why data not shown in release apk but shown in debug Apk after changing in room database and firebase firestore in android kotlin?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

Here is my app which is available in the Play Store. Unfortunately, a client told me to add one more field in the database which I did in Firebase Firestore and room database because the app reads first from Firestore then adds data in the room database, and finally reads data from the room database. when I run the app as default (debug mode) results show as expected but when I run the app in release mode the data is not shown i do not know why. I already changed the schema version of the room database and database name.

I ran the app in release mode and added some toasts in the reading method of Firebase which is shown on the screen but I think the data was not added and read from the room database. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you share some code on how you are reading from your database and from firestore? Also, did you add a migration when you updated the schema?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Bilal asked for, and please also respond using @.